# How can I grab just the first letters of a string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am passing a username in a session like below and would like to get the first letter of the first name and last name. So for example Doe, John I would like to get "JD" etc. Any idea how I would do this? Thank you

```
Session("Username")
```

Comment: You don't know how to get a substring in VB.NET?

Comment: You username is always stored with the lastname in first position and the firstname in last position and you want the initials in fist/last order?

Comment: Yes, lastname first and firstname last. I never tried substring I will need to look it up

Comment: If you can, a possibility could be to store a Person class with the first and last name as seperate properties. With functions like GetFullName(), GetInitials()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example following your requirements. Lastname stored in first position and firstname stored in last position, but the order of the returned string is First/Last

```
string username = "Doe, John";
string[] parts = username.Split(' ');
string result = parts[1].Substring(0,1) + parts[0].Substring(0,1);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

No error checking is present for clarity, but if you want this for a real work some checks on length of parts is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

If you have only spaces between the parts of the username, try with this RegEx :

```
initials = Regex.Replace(Session("Username")," *([^ ])[^ ]*","$1")
```

--> the string "[^ ]" gets every character which is not a space (you can add the char '-' if you want)

By this way, you get a solution which works with people called "John Joe Jibbs" ^^

**This is just a proof of concept.**